# SQL Create View By Combining Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table:

| FieldName | ValueChar | ValueNum | ValueBool | SubmissionID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Color | Red | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| CrayonNumber | NULL | 38 | NULL | 1 |
| IsToxic | NULL | NULL | TRUE | 1 |
| CrayonCreatorName | Bob | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| Color | Blue | NULL | NULL | 2 |
| CrayonNumber | NULL | 17 | NULL | 2 |
| IsToxic | NULL | NULL | FALSE | 2 |

I'd like to create a view that when queried would return:

| Color | CrayonNumber | IsToxic | CrayonCreatorName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 38 | TRUE | Bob |
| Blue | 17 | FALSE | NULL |

Is this possible without stored procedures?

Comment: Write a SELECT statement using appropriate SQL and you have what you want.

Comment: "A view is a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query."

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I understand this, however I am (at the moment) unsure of how to write a query to accomplish this. Hence the question.

Comment: It would help if you added DDL for the table and the expected data types for the result columns. That saves us from guessing things like what `ValueBool` is since it can't be [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select SubmissionID,
       max(case when fieldname = 'Color' then ValueChar end) as color,
       max(case when fieldname = 'CrayonNumber' then ValueChar end) as CrayonNumber,
       max(case when fieldname = 'IsToxic' then ValueBool end) as IsToxic,
       max(case when fieldname = 'CrayonCreatorName' then ValueChar end) as CrayonCreatorName
from t
group by SubmissionID;
```